# Keep multiple changes in a shiny app after updating values

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app in which there are two tables. As you can see the user uses the right datatable and the widgets there in order to display the results in the rhandsontable on the left. The app works as expected except that the fact every time I choose a different Test by the `selectInput()` "Label" all the previous changes I have made are lost and the rhandsontable on the left "restarts". I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981821/how-to-use-reactivevalues-in-order-to-store-changes-in-a-shiny-app) in order to keep the modified names but I need to apply a similar logic to the whole app.

**Logic of the app:**

The user chooses one of the Tests by using the selectInput() "Label". This is the main operation and then he is able to modify its name, for example Test 1 to Test A. Then the user can add items in the Test by the numericInput() "Items in Test". These are the total items. As you will see the number of "Items in Test" is the same with 'Avail' column in hot3 table for the choosen Test. With "Select Items" he can choose specific items to be displayed in the hot5 table. Then the user can click on the hot5 table to select a specific item and the number of selected items (or rows) is displayed in the hot3 table under "Sel" column for this specific Test. The 'Items chosen' just displayes the number of Items selected in "Select Items". Note that every modification that happens to the table is not dependent on the other widgets. That means for example that it is not necessary to change a Label Name.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("Booklets",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2"),
               rHandsontableOutput("hot3")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               fluidRow(
                 wellPanel(
                   fluidRow(
                     column(4,
                            DT::dataTableOutput("hot5")       
                     ),
                     column(4,
                            fluidRow(
                              uiOutput("book3"),
                              uiOutput("book6")

                            ),
                            fluidRow(
                              uiOutput("book1"),
                              uiOutput("book10"),
                              uiOutput("book11")
                            )
                     )
                   ))
               )
             )
           )
  )
  )
#server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2", "#tests", value = 1, min=1)
  })

  output$book1<-renderUI({
    numericInput("bk1", 
                 "Items in test", 
                 value = 1,
                 min = 1)
  })
  output$book3<-renderUI({

    selectInput("bk3", 
                "Label", 
                choices=(paste("Test",1:input$text2)))
  })


  output$book6<-renderUI({
    textInput("bk6", "Change to",
              value=NULL
    )
  })


  output$book10<-renderUI({
    selectizeInput(
      "bk10", "Select Items", choices =1:10000,multiple =T,selected = 1,
      options = list(maxItems = input$bk1))
  })
  output$book11<-renderUI({
    textInput("bk11", "Items chosen",
              value = nrow(rt5())
    )
  })


  rt4<-reactive({

    if(is.null(input$bk6)|input$bk6==""){
      if(is.null(input$hot5_rows_selected)|| is.na(input$hot5_rows_selected)){
        DF=data.frame(
          Sel. = rep(TRUE, input$text2),
          Test=paste(1:input$text2),
          Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
          Avail.=format(round(as.integer(rep.int(input$bk1,input$text2))),0),
          Sel =as.integer(rep.int(0,input$text2)),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      }
      else{
        DF=data.frame(
          Sel. = rep(TRUE, input$text2),
          Test=paste(1:input$text2),
          Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
          Avail.=format(round(as.integer(rep.int(input$bk1,input$text2))),0),
          Sel =as.integer(rep.int(0,input$text2)),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      }
      for(i in 1 : input$text2){
        if(DF[i,3]==input$bk3){
          DF[i,4]<-input$bk1
          DF[i,5]<-length(input$hot5_rows_selected)
        }
        else{
          DF[i,4]<-1

        }
      }

      DF
    }
    else{
      if(is.null(input$hot5_rows_selected)|| is.na(input$hot5_rows_selected)){
        DF=data.frame(
          Sel. = rep(TRUE, input$text2),
          Test=paste(1:input$text2),
          Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
          Avail.=format(round(as.integer(rep.int(input$bk1,input$text2))),0),
          Sel =as.integer(rep.int(0,input$text2)),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        DF[DF==input$bk3]<-input$bk6
        DF
      }
      else{
        DF=data.frame(
          Sel. = rep(TRUE, input$text2),
          Test=paste(1:input$text2),
          Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
          Avail.=format(round(as.integer(rep.int(input$bk1,input$text2))),0),
          Sel =as.integer(rep.int(0,input$text2)),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        DF[DF==input$bk3]<-input$bk6
        DF
      }

      for(i in 1 : input$text2){
        if(DF[i,3]==input$bk6){
          DF[i,4]<-input$bk1
          DF[i,5]<-length(input$hot5_rows_selected)
        }
        else{
          DF[i,4]<-1

        }
      }
      DF
    }

  })

  rt55<-reactive({
    DF=data.frame(
      Id=  input$bk10,
      Label=paste("Item",input$bk10),
      Pf=0,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  })

  rt5<-reactive({
    DF=data.frame(
      Id=  input$bk10,
      Label=paste("Item",input$bk10),
      Pf=0,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    cbind(id=rowSelected(), DF)
  })

  rowSelected <- reactive({
    x <- numeric(nrow(rt55()))
    x[input$hot5_rows_selected] <- 1
    x
  })

  output$hot5 <- renderDT(datatable(rt5()[,-1],
                                    selection = list(mode = "multiple",
                                                     selected = (1:nrow(rt5()[,-1]))[as.logical(rowSelected())],
                                                     target = "row"),rownames = F)
  )



  output$hot3 <-renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(rt4())

  )



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made edits based on comments. I think the code works, but its fairly fragile and needs a fair degree of error handling. Resetting entriesafter submit is hit, for instance

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)
#library(tidyverse)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("Booklets",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2"),
               rHandsontableOutput("hot3")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               fluidRow(
                 wellPanel(
                   fluidRow(
                     column(4,
                            DT::dataTableOutput("hot5")
                     ),
                     column(4,
                            fluidRow(
                              uiOutput("book3"),
                              uiOutput("book6")

                            ),
                            fluidRow(
                              uiOutput("book1"),
                              uiOutput("book10"),
                              uiOutput("book11")
                            ),
                            fluidRow(actionButton("submit","submit"))
                     )
                   ))
               )
             )
           )
  )
)
#server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv<-reactiveValues()

  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2", "#tests", value = 1, min=1)
  })

  output$book1<-renderUI({
    numericInput("bk1",
                 "Items in test",
                 value = 1,
                 min = 1)
  })

  output$book3<-renderUI({

    selectInput("bk3",
                "Label",
                choices=(paste("Test",1:input$text2)))

  })


  output$book6<-renderUI({
    textInput("bk6", "Change to",
              value=NULL
    )
  })


  output$book10<-renderUI({
    # changed from selectize
    selectizeInput(
      "bk10", "Select Items", choices =1:10000,multiple =T,selected = 1,
      options = list(maxItems = input$bk1))#changed from
  })
  output$book11<-renderUI({
    textInput("bk11", "Items chosen",
              value = nrow(rt5())
    )
  })

  #rt4<-reactive({
  observe({
    req(input$text2)

    rv$rt4 = data.frame(
      SNo = rep(TRUE, input$text2),
      Test=paste(1:input$text2),
      Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
      Avail=1L,
      Sel =as.integer(rep.int(0,input$text2)),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit,{

 # rt4 <- reactive({
    if (is.null( rv$rt4))
      return(NULL)

    if(!is.null(input$bk6) && input$bk6!=""){
      rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==input$bk3, "Avail"] <- input$bk1
      rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==(input$bk3), "Sel"] <- length(input$hot5_rows_selected)

      rv$rt4[ rv$rt4$Label==input$bk3, "Label"] <- input$bk6
    }
    # if(!is.null(input$hot5_rows_selected) && input$hot5_rows_selected!=""){
    #
    # }
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit,{

    updateSelectInput(session,"bk3","Label", choices=rv$rt4$Label)
  }
  )


  rt55<-reactive({
    DF=data.frame(
      Id=  input$bk10,
      Label=paste("Item",input$bk10),
      Pf=0,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  })

  rt5<-reactive({
    DF=data.frame(
      Id=  input$bk10,
      Label=paste("Item",input$bk10),
      Pf=0,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    cbind(id=rowSelected(), DF)
  })

  rowSelected <- reactive({
    x <- numeric(nrow(rt55()))
    x[input$hot5_rows_selected] <- 1
    x
  })

  output$hot5 <- renderDT(datatable(rt5()[,-1],
                                    selection = list(mode = "multiple",
                                                     selected = (1:nrow(rt5()[,-1]))[as.logical(rowSelected())],
                                                     target = "row"),rownames = F)
  )

  output$hot3 <-renderRHandsontable({
    req(input$text2)
    rhandsontable(rv$rt4)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you but now the changes happen to all the selected Tests and not only in the one that is chosen by the selectInput() 'Label'. If you check my initial code you will understand the use of the app exactly as it works. The problem is that it cannot keep the values.

Comment: Can you explain that a little further? Right now the user has two ways to change the table hot3. Either by selecting the label of his choice from the bk3 input, and then changes the value to what is input in bk6. Or by directly editing values in hot3 rhandontable.Is that not the desired output?

Comment: Thank for your time again. I edited the Q in order to give more details about the app logic. The hot3 table should be modified only through the hot5 table and the widgets there.

Comment: I understood the logic now. Would it be okay to introduce a Submit button(action button)?

Comment: No problem at all, since the app is functional.

Comment: For clearer instruction you can just run my app and see what is described above.

Comment: How important is this initialization. Avail.=format(round(as.integer(rep.int(input$bk1,(input$text2))),0)). Can you initialize this without input$bk1

Comment: This has to display the number of available items. Selected or not.Does this cause an issue?When the app starts it can be "1" but as I choose more items it should take bk1 as input.

Comment: Note that if you can think of a more efficient or clever way you are welcome!

Comment: I changed some column names (Avail. to Avail, Sel. to SNo). Those changes are only stylistic and cosmetic

Comment: I see. Do you believe the original question is possible to be solved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178686/discussion-between-ashleych-and-firmo23).